# Efficient way to wrap column names of proportion tables in rmarkdown pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, kableextra, kable

I'm making weighted tables of row proportions using the questionr package. I want to wrap the column names when they are too long. Because I'm making hundreds of tables, the solution needs to work on tables with varying numbers of columns. I also want to avoid setting all columns to a specific width. Ideally, short column names would remain at their normal width while names exceeding the specified maximum length would be wrapped.

Here are a bunch of solutions I've tried so far, written as .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(questionr)
library(knitr)
data("happy")
```


A simple weighted table with the "kable" method:
```{r table1, echo=TRUE}
kable(wtd.table(happy$degree, happy$happy, weights = happy$wtssall),
  digits = 0)
```

The same "kable" table, but with row proportions:
```{r table2, echo=TRUE}
kable(rprop(wtd.table(happy$degree, happy$happy, weights = happy$wtssall)),
  digits = 0)
```

I want to wrap the column headers, but kableExtra::column_spec() gives an error.
Even if it worked it requires manually setting each column width.:
```{r table3, echo=TRUE}
library(kableExtra)
kable(rprop(wtd.table(happy$degree, happy$happy, weights = happy$wtssall)),
  digits = 0) %>%
  column_spec(column = 2, width = ".25in")
```

Maybe str_wrap will do the trick?
```{r table4, echo=TRUE}
library(stringr)
kable(rprop(wtd.table(happy$degree, str_wrap(happy$happy, width = 8),
                  weights = happy$wtssall)),
  digits = 0)
```

Giving up on knitr::kable(), maybe pander has a solution.
Here is the simple weighted frequency table.
```{r table5, echo=TRUE, results='asis'}
library(pander)
pandoc.table(wtd.table(happy$degree, str_wrap(happy$happy, width = 8),
                  weights = happy$wtssall),
         split.cells=8)
```

So far, so good. But it doesn't work for the table of row proportions,
because the rprop table is of class ([1]"proptab" [2]"table")
while the wtd.table() is just class "table"
```{r table6, echo=TRUE, results='asis', error=TRUE}
pandoc.table(rprop(wtd.table(happy$degree, str_wrap(happy$happy, width = 8),
                  weights = happy$wtssall)),
         split.cells=8)
```

But wait! I can pass a kable() product as pandoc output.
This table looks great, but I don't think I pass any
pandoc.table() arguments like "split.cells=8" to it.
```{r table7, echo=TRUE, results='asis', error=TRUE}
kable(rprop(wtd.table(happy$degree, happy$happy, weights = happy$wtssall)),
  digits = 0, format = "pandoc")
```
````

And here is what the output of that .Rmd file looks like:[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least, for `kableExtra`, you need to specify format in your `kable` function to be either `latex` or `html`. 
[image]

To make it dynamic, you can save the table to a variable before it goes into kable and use 2:(ncol(your_table) + 1) in the `column_spec` function (+1 for the column_name column).

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I was looking for. The outstanding issue is that this solution makes all columns 0.5in wide. In my question I'm trying to set a maximum column width. I'd like to avoid stretching shorter columns.

Comment: Also, here's a 1-line solution to making the table length dynamic: `column = 2:(length(unique(happy$happy[!is.na(happy$happy)])))`