# Wrap add_header_above in Rmd pdf output

Tags: latex, r-markdown, kableextra

**Question**

How to wrap header above (inserted by `add_header_above()`)?

[There is a simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254485/4552295) to do it to one layered header but doesn't work when there is a second (or third) of header.

**Reproducible example**

```
library(kableExtra)
names(iris) <- c("L", "W", "L", "W", " ")
iris[1:2, ] %>% 
  kable("latex") %>% 
  add_header_above(
    c(
      "Sepal is great" = 2, 
      "Petal is better, (in fac my favorite)" = 2, 
      "nc" = 1)
    ) %>%
  column_spec(2:ncol(iris), width = "0.3in")
```

**Current output looks**

[image]

**Expected output from R code (roughly)**

[image]

Comment: In the end, I just want to have the table fit on one page and preferably continue using kable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in [Best Practice for newline in LaTeX table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf), if you need newlines inside all kableExtra functions, just use `\n`. Otherwise, you can try out the `linebreak` function.

```
library(kableExtra)
names(iris) <- c("L", "W", "L", "W", " ")
iris[1:2, ] %>% 
  kable("latex") %>% 
  add_header_above(
    c(
      "Sepal\nis great" = 2, 
      "Petal is better,\n(in fac my favorite)" = 2, 
      "nc" = 1)
    ) %>%
  column_spec(2:ncol(iris), width = "0.3in")
```